# Transform array of objects in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, json

I have JSON with one object for each site's traffic for 3 dates.

I want to merge these three objects together on "Date". Example below.

I'm using Ruby. What is the easiest way to do this?

**Start JSON:**

```
 [  
   {  
      "Google":[  
         {  
            "Date":"2015-01-01",
            "Value":100
         },
         {  
            "Date":"2015-02-01",
            "Value":200
         },
         {  
            "Date":"2015-03-01",
            "Value":300
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "Yahoo":[  
         {  
            "Date":"2015-01-01",
            "Value":1200
         },
         {  
            "Date":"2015-02-01",
            "Value":1300
         },
         {  
            "Date":"2015-03-01",
            "Value":1400
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "Bing":[  
         {  
            "Date":"2015-01-01",
            "Value":500
         },
         {  
            "Date":"2015-02-01",
            "Value":600
         },
         {  
            "Date":"2015-03-01",
            "Value":700
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

**End JSON:**

```
[
  {  
    "Date":"2015-01-01",
    "Google":100,
    "Yahoo":1200,
    "Bing":500
  },
  {  
    "Date":"2015-01-02",
    "Google":200,
    "Yahoo":1200,
    "Bing":600
  },
  {  
    "Date":"2015-01-03",
    "Google":300,
    "Yahoo":1400,
    "Bing":700
  }
]
```

Comment: i would use map reduce in mongo for that, but if you want in Ruby, think about http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by and JSON parse/dump

Comment: I don't see any JSON things in the question.

Comment: @undur_gongor Author mentioned that he has a json data.

Comment: @CodeGroover: But all the presented data are just plain Ruby data (arrays, hashes, strings), no JSON.

Comment: @undur_gongor "I have JSON ... " and "I'm using Ruby ..." and he posted 2 json examples. i can assume on backend side he is doing parsing, e.g. via Rails, but i just assumed that he just got JSON files and he want to write system script using Ruby. End of story.

Comment: You're both right :) 

- The data started as JSON, then I just did `JSON.parse`, so yes the question is really just concerned with arrays of hashes. 

The JSON tag just helps people that are looking to merge similar JSON structures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
result = array.inject({}) do | a, e | 
  site, data = e.first
  data.each do | x | 
    a[x[:Date]] ||= {}
    a[x[:Date]][site] = x[:Value]
  end
  a
end
```

gives you a hash with the dates as keys. This can be transformed to the array by:

```
result.map { | k, v | v.update(:Date => k) }
```

Comment: And accumulation part a[x[:Date]][site] ? a[x[:Date]][site] += x[:Value] :  x[:Value] and also the target result is array

Comment: also after JSON parsing it has keys as Strings not a Symbols.

Comment: @CodeGroover: You are right with the array-vs-hash remark. Thank you.

Comment: sorry, no accumulation of course, it is just a transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming exactly this structure, what might work is

```
results = [] 

your_array[0]['Google'].each_with_index do |item, index|
  date = item['Date']

  provider_values = your_array.inject({}) do |memo, current|
    provider = current.keys[0]
    value = current[provider][index]['Value']

    memo[provider] = value
    memo
  end 
  results.push({'Date' => date}.merge(provider_values))
end
```

I'm currently on Windows so I can't be 100% sure of correctness, however fixing any syntax errors should be easy.